# Adding elements to a keyvaluepair List

Tags: c#, arrays, list, dictionary, key-value

I have the following bit of code and would like to add it to a keyvaluepair List/Array/Dictionary whichever works best.

A little background:
Presently this snippet is interacting directly with the DB and it's inside a loop that pushes to the DB on each iteration that the data is made. My overall intent is to push this data to a list/dictionary etc so that I can push all the data to DB at once. Here is is:

```
 _dataContext.GetRepository<UserRole, Guid>().Insert(new[]
        {
            new UserRole
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                UserId = newGroup.CreatedById,
                RoleId = SecurityConstants.RoleId.GROUP_ADMINISTRATOR,
                GroupId = newGroup.Id,
                CreatedById = newGroup.CreatedById
            },
            new UserRole
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                RoleId = SecurityConstants.RoleId.CONTACT_PERSON,
                UserId = newGroup.CreatedById,
                GroupId = newGroup.Id,
                CreatedById = newGroup.CreatedById
            }
        });
```

The above GetRepository then accesses the DB as outlined above. I would like to store the data separately in whichever way works so that I may push it to the DB later

```
 public interface IMydDataContext : IDisposable
{
    IRepository<TEntity, TKrey> GetRepository<TEntity, TKrey>() where TEntity : class, IDomainObject<TKrey>;
    IDbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity, TKey>() where TEntity : class, IDomainObject<TKey>;
    int SaveChanges();
    Task<int> SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

I declare the dictionary here:

```
Dictionary<UserRole, Guid> _usersRepositoryDictionary = new     Dictionary<UserRole, Guid>();
```

and attempt to put the data in it this way:

```
_usersRepositoryDictionary.Add(new[] { new UserRole
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
            UserId = newGroup.CreatedById,
            RoleId = SecurityConstants.RoleId.GROUP_ADMINISTRATOR,
            GroupId = newGroup.Id,
            CreatedById = newGroup.CreatedById
        },
            new UserRole
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
            RoleId = SecurityConstants.RoleId.CONTACT_PERSON,
            UserId = newGroup.CreatedById,
            GroupId = newGroup.Id,
            CreatedById = newGroup.CreatedById
        }
        });
```

However I get an error indicator over the "Add" that says, "there is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'value' of Dictionary.Add(UserRole,Guid)"

Any clue what I am doing wrong?

Comment: And what is the problem? In particular: where does `Insert` store your data?

Comment: Insert sends the data to a custom repository for Db access @HimBromBeere I just added it as an edit above

Comment: I don't really get what the issue is but I think you can use a Dictionary<UserRole, Guid> just fine.

Comment: So you'd recommend a Dictionary over a keyvaluepair list in this case @RaulA.

Comment: If you have unique keys, probably Guid would be best used as key, I think a dictionary would be fine and perhaps more easy to work with by querying directly based on the key.

Comment: Thank you. Will implement and return with results

Comment: Hi @RaulA. so I attempted to use a dictionary as noted above but got an error still. Wonder what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: 1) I would suggest to use `Dictionary<Guid, UserRole>` since Guid should be unique and it'e easier to use that as a key.
2) The Add method will take a key and value as parameters so you need to do `Add(yourGuid, yourUserRole)` or just `dict[yourGuid]=yourUserRole`. If you want to put an array there you need to define the dictionary in a different manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define your dictionary like this:

```
Dictionary<UserRole, Guid> _usersRepositoryDictionary = new     Dictionary<UserRole, Guid>();
```

and you add to it like this:

```
        _usersRepositoryDictionary.Add(new[] { new UserRole
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
            UserId = newGroup.CreatedById,
            RoleId = SecurityConstants.RoleId.GROUP_ADMINISTRATOR,
            GroupId = newGroup.Id,
            CreatedById = newGroup.CreatedById
        },
            new UserRole
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
            RoleId = SecurityConstants.RoleId.CONTACT_PERSON,
            UserId = newGroup.CreatedById,
            GroupId = newGroup.Id,
            CreatedById = newGroup.CreatedById
        }
        });
```

You are adding to it **dict.Add(new UserRole[] {...})** when you should add **dict.Add(UserRole, Guid)**;

You need something like this:

```
    var userRole = new UserRole
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
        UserId = newGroup.CreatedById,
        RoleId = SecurityConstants.RoleId.GROUP_ADMINISTRATOR,
        GroupId = newGroup.Id,
        CreatedById = newGroup.CreatedById
    };

    _usersRepositoryDictionary.Add(userRole, userRole.Id);
```

And now it can be clear that the Id info is pretty much redundant, so I suggest a better abstraction of your data models (e.g. something that inherits IEntity which has an Id property).

Comment: this solution most definitley works. Thank you. I do have an issue using this list with the GetRepository function mentioned in the second part of my question. I will post that in a second question however. I consider this answer to the solution to the above mentioned problem of ADDING an KEY,VALUE PAIR to a list.

Comment: Can you specify a bit more clearly the second problem in your question (the one with GetRepository) so we can mark this as resolved? I didn't quite get the issue.

Comment: this specific question is resolved as the relevant data has been added to the list as requested. I have marked it as such. FYI the second question basically how to save this to the database is called: "Adding a KeyValue List OR Dictionary to a DBInterface"